# What is the last version of Skype that will run on OS X 10.5 for a PPC Mac?

Tags: mac-mini, leopard, skype, powerpc

I've got a G4 Mac Mini that is running 10.5.8 and the latest version of Skype (v 5.3) will not install on my machine because it is Intel only. What is the last version that would work on PowerPC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for Skype 2.8.0.866 (PPC), which you can find searching the [OldApps](http://mac.oldapps.com/skype.php?system=mac_os_x_10.5_leopard_powerpc) website. It was released on 29 November, 2010.

> Supported Systems: Mac OS X 10.5 Leopard (PowerPC)

Comment: Yes, Martin is right. You need to download the older version of Skype 2.8.0.866 for your Mac PPC.